# Sampling Distribution of Variances Another Exmaple

Tags: probability, statistics

Below is a problem I did but my answer does not match the book. The problem is from the book "Probability and Statistics" which is one of Schaum's books. I am using the second edition. I am hoping somebody can tell me where I went wrong or that the book is wrong. I suspect the book is right.
Thanks
Bob
Problem:
A normal population has a variance of $15$. If samples of size $5$ are drawn from
this population, what percentage are be expected to have variances more than $20$.
Answer
Let $p_{20}$ be the probability that the sample variance is under $20$. Let $p$ be
the probability we seek. Now we have $p = 1 - p_{20}$. To find $p_{20}$ we go
to the online calculator with $4$ degrees of freedom. The chi-square
critical value is $4(\frac{20}{15}) = 5.3333333$. From the calculator we get: $p_{20} = 0.75$. Hence, $p = 0.25$.
Note: The calculator can be found at this URL:
      https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/chi-square.aspx
The book gets: $p = 0.17$.

Comment: Like [your similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2900724/sampling-distribution-of-variances) this may come down to the definition of *sample variance* using $\frac1n$ or $\frac1{n-1}$.  Try $5(\frac{20}{15})\approx 6.6667$ instead so in R `1 - pchisq(5*20/15, 4)` which gives `0.1545873`

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the response. I tired what you suggested before I posted here. However, as you see, you get a different answer then what the book as. Do you think the book is wrong?

Comment: @Henry: I get same answer as you (both from `pchisq` and by simulation) if sample variance is defined with $n$ in denom. // Important to use df=4 as you have done, not df=5. Changing def'n of $S^2$ doesn't change dist'n of $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X_1, X_2, \dots X_5$ is a random sample from
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma=\sqrt{15}),$ then
$Q = 4S^2/15 \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(4),$ where
$S^2$ is the sample variance.

Thus, $$P(S^2 > 20) = P\left(\frac{4S^2}{15} > \frac{4(20)}{15} = 5.3333\right) = 0.2548.$$
Computation in R statistical software:

```
1 - pchisq(16/3, 4)
[1] 0.2547727
```

*Note:* The simulation below with a million such samples of size $n=5$ agrees with this result within the margin of simulation error. (Two or three place accuracy can be
expected.)

```
set.seed(918)
v = replicate( 10^6,  var(rnorm(5, 0, sqrt(15))) )
mean(v > 20)
[1] 0.25556
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your answer makes sense to me. However, the book gets $0.17$. Do you think the book is wrong?

Comment: If you're studying probability on your own, I'd recommend a standard undergrad intro text such as Scheaffer, perhaps you can find an inexpensive older edition online with a matching student answer guide. (That is the probability part of a Stat book by Wackerly et al, which I have used in my classes.) Also Grinstead and Snell have posted a free PDF of their probability book on the Dartmouth site. I haven't used it for a class, but often for examples and ref. In any case, I'd always want access to a 2nd book in case of difficulties with my 1st.

Comment: Fixing small typo in prev comment: If the question refers to the sample variance, defined as $S^2=\frac{1}{n−1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i−\bar X)^2$ and you seek $P(S^2>20),$ then I think the probability is 0.2548. // If the sample variance is defined with denom $n$ instead of $n−1,$ then the my formula $Q\sim$ CHISQ(4) needs modification. // I know some people are fans of Schaum Outlines and I respect their view, but don't understand it.